# Adding block inside a block Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, xml

I am trying to add a block inside a block in footer links. I am trying the following code.

```
<referenceBlock name="footer_links">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="Delivery">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Delivery</argument>
            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">living.html</argument>
        </arguments>

                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="jamaal">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Jamaal</argument>
            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">living.html</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>


    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```